# $http call is taking more time than server execution time

Tags: .net, angularjs, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using AngularJS as clientside framework for my application , I am calling server  code by following format.

**Call From Angular controller to MVC Actionmethod**

```
 FormActions.POST('/MVCControllerName/MVCActionMethodName', ParameterForActionMethod).success(function (data) { 
//Do someting
});
```

I have defined FormActions as Angular service as follows

```
function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};

AppFactory.factory('FormActions', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        //Get Generic Function .
        GET: function (url, Object) {
            return $http({
                url: url + '?Id=' + generateUUID(),
                cache: false,                  
                params: { obj: Object }
            });
        },
        POST: function (url, data) {
            return $http.post(url, {  data: data, cache: false });
        }

    };
}]);
```

Now whenever I am giving a call from angular controller to MVC action method its taking almost 5-7 seconds (measured using fiddler and network tab in browser )for a simple action method execution also.

Kindly help me out if I am doing any configuration mistake or code level mistake so that I can reduce response time for call.

Comment: But it is a slow response or slow script? However you tried to comment the part of the UUID generation and assign a static id for testing?
And if the problem persists means that the problem is server-side.

Comment: I tried with static ID as well but still the problem persists , also server side code is getting executed in 0.05 milliseconds.

Comment: so, the script  angularjs is fast, server script is fast but the response of server is in 5-6 second? maybe you can try make a new simple service with a simple request without request to db to see if the prblem is db request

Comment: Yes in fiddler it is showing that call took 5-6 seconds and from server side I have just passed the Constant value in JSONResult.

Comment: Can you post your HTML which you are displaying result ?

Comment: @Angular_10 its just simple html like below:
<input id="parentName" type="text" ng-model="Name" name="name" />

Comment: What server you have?

Comment: I am checking this with local dev server only means VS2013 , IIS 8.0 and Machine config like 8GB RAM.